# react err with use setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting the following error when trying to use setState on a single component.

Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

- I created the list in the state.
- On a button I want to update the list

my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { sistemas: [] };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log('Indo buscar dados');
    this.setState({
      sistemas: [
        { id: '1', nome: 'sistema1' },
        { id: '2', nome: 'sistema2' },
        { id: '3', nome: 'sistema3' }
      ]
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <button className='button' onClick={this.handleClick}>
          Click Me
      </button>
        <p>{this.state.sistemas}</p>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <div>
          <ul>
            {this.state.sistemas.map(sistema => <li>{sistema}</li>)}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

You have to add `key` attribute to rendered components when using `map()` function

```
<ul>
    {this.state.sistemas.map(sistema => <li key={sistema.id}>{sistema}</li>)}
</ul>
```

Comment: But it's better to use some unique id as a key if you have it instead of index.

Answer (score 1):

use Arrow function to setState then map the data by the id

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { sistemas: [] };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    console.log('Indo buscar dados');
    this.setState({
      sistemas: [
        { id: '1', nome: 'sistema1' },
        { id: '2', nome: 'sistema2' },
        { id: '3', nome: 'sistema3' }
      ]
    })
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.sistemas, 'check this')
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <button className='button' onClick={this.handleClick}>
          Click Me
      </button>
        <div>
          <ul>
            {this.state.sistemas.map(sistema => 
              <li key={sistema.id}>{sistema.nome}</li>
            )}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[image: Edit 61jqz3yklw]